# Calling an intent two types

Tags: android, android-intent

When calling an intent I see two types:

1. public Intent (Context packageContext, Class cls)
2. public Intent setClassName (Context packageContext, String className)

Which should be used when?

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Comment: Is there a situation where you're torn on which to use? Seems more hypothetical than dire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the first one, it is easier and takes only 1 line of code:

```
new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
```

You only need to use the second form if you don't know the class at compile time (ie: you need to choose the class at runtime and you only have its name as a String).

Comment: I see but in the code I am reviewing, I see it as intent.setClassName(this, myclass.class.getName());  Here I know the class name as "myclass". Please help

Comment: Show more of this code, please. How is the Intent created? What other methods are called on it?

Comment: The code snippet is 
@Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
  Intent intent = getIntent();
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
  intent.setClassName(this,myclass.class.getName());
   startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
   finish();
 }

Comment: In the code snippet you provided, the developer is reusing an existing `Intent` (which probably already has certain EXTRAS set, or the ACTION or DATA fields. He is redirecting this `Intent` to another activity by setting the class name. Does that make sense?